# How to render a field above the node title using omega sub-theme

Tags: theming

I am trying to render a slideshow in a node above the page title

So far I have in my template.php

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  $theme = alpha_get_theme();
  if ($vars['elements']['#region'] == 'content') {
    $vars['node'] = $theme->page['node'];
  }
}
```

this passes a $node variable into a custom region--content.tpl.php
I was then expecting to be able to use this snippet to render the field but it fails

```
print render($node['field_slideshow_images']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might get a bit more luck using the [`field_view_field`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) function:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  $theme = alpha_get_theme();
  if ($vars['elements']['#region'] == 'content') {
    $node = $theme->page['node'];

    $vars['slideshow'] = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_slideshow_images');
  }
}
```

And then use `print render($slideshow);` in your template file.

You might need to play with the 4th parameter to `field_view_field()` (`$display`) a bit if you have custom settings on your display for that field, but it should be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks Clive, this has done the job. Display 'default' and it has triggered the slideshow module. Unfortunately though the inline styles from jquery.cycle are not present so the images are not sliding. I shall investigate further.

Comment: @James Hah I only just realised which James you are. See you next week mate :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who needs to do this, here is a shorter version with better validation and using menu_get_object instead of getting the node from the theme.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_region(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['elements']['#region'] == 'content') {
    if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
      $vars['slideshow'] = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_slideshow_images', 'default');
    }
  }
}
```

Then in region--content.tpl.php

```
print render($slideshow);
```