# Omega 4 outputting fields into layout template

Tags: entities, theming

What's the easiest way to output a field into an Omega 4 subtheme layout?

I normally use Zen where it would be:

```
<?php
print render($content['field_NAME']);
?>
```

But with Omega $content is null. I tried the suggestions at [How to render a field above the node title using omega sub-theme](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49283/how-to-render-a-field-above-the-node-title-using-omega-sub-theme) but couldn't get any output from that either.

Any ideas?

Comment: in which template do you want to render a field? in page.tpl.php?

Comment: I'm using a copy of one of the Omega 4 layout templates.

Comment: There are many different places within a layout where you can output something, so – where exactly should the field be rendered? In a block? In a region? In the node.tpl? Can you give us a bit more details? In which file did you write print render($content['field_NAME']);?

Comment: The file i'm using is in sites/all/themes/omega_subtheme/layouts/project/project-layout.tpl.php

By default it's using `<?php print render($page['content']); ?>` but I'd like to output the fields individually.

Comment: For future searchers, this worked for me: https://www.drupal.org/node/2223069.